# Changing Wix background

Tags: visual-studio, wix

Hi and hello to everyone. I've been trying to edit or rather change the background of my installer which I created using Wix. Take note that this is my first time and I have no idea completely when it comes to XML and also in WIX. Kindly advice and help. Thanks.

I have this code which I found on another site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject2" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="628c5ddd-baee-48ba-8b16-bad2cb70862b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject2" Level="1">
    </Feature>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
<Binary Id="Idnumber1" SourceFile="img\banner.png" />

</Product>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First question. Do you have the pro version (or paid version)?

Comment: @KRUKUSA WiX has a paid version?

Comment: I'm using a free version sir. I want to test it out sir and I don't have money to buy one. :(

Comment: I assume you've taken a look at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

Comment: It took me a bit of googling to find this out, it's been a while since I worked on Wix. But there is a tool set called "Wix Toolset" I believe that should get you headed in the right direction

Comment: Yes I did. But it does not state there where should I put the code I saw. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: I even read the tutorial but I still can't find out where to insert that code to change the background. When I insert the code there are two results. 1 is it does not change and 2nd is it disappears.

Comment: I update the script maybe you guys can understand it better than I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use this line

```
<Binary Id="Idnumber1" SourceFile="img\banner.png" />
```

to set the background then that's your problem.
If you are setting the background you want to use the WixUIDialogBmp variable.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="path to your bmp"/>
```

Additionally as you can see [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) all the images need to be bitmaps. The file in your example is a png, the WixUIDialogBmp will also need to be 493 x 312.

Also [WixToolSet](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/) has lots of good walk-throughs and guides, in addition to the documentation.